# Vuforia and Azure Spatial Anchors (ASA) does not work in Vuforia on HoloLens

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, azure-spatial-anchors, ar-foundation

When I try to use both Azure Spatial Anchors (ASA) and Vuforia in a Unity project, I get a "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error in the initialization of Vuforia.

- It does work in Unity Play mode, but crashes in HoloLens
- It does not matter whether I use delayed Initialization or not
- My versions are Unity 2020.3.24f1, Vuforia 10.3.2, Azure Spatial Anchors SDK Core/Windows 2.12.0

When I remove Azure Spatial Anchors SDK Core/Windows and include ARFoundaton, it also crashes with the same error. I do see some switching of arfoundation versions in the VuforiaConfiguration, so likely it is related to ARFoundation, which is also used by the Azure anchors.

I tried updating Azure anchor versions, through package manager. This did upgrade the internal ARFoundation version of VuforiaConfiguration, but that did not fix it. When it indicates version 4.1.9 when without Azure anchors it seems to work, but this is reset as soon as I include anchor Azure anchors again and start building. The versions it had where it did not work are 4.0.12 (old Azure Anchors package) 4.1.13 (new latest Azure anchor package)

I did not yet upgrade the Vuforia version, because this is a breaking update always and takes considerable time.

We really need both functionalities, so I hope there is a solution to this. Thanks

Comment: Solved: I tested removing component ARSession and indeed this solves this issue. Can both track with Vuforia and download Azure Spatial Anchors again

Answer (score -1):

I am also trying to find a solution to this problem. I have identified it. Vuforia and ASA need the camera both but vuforia monopolizes it so we have to switch the use of the camera between these two SDK. If you have an idea tell me ;)

Comment: Yes indeed the same thing @patsu. Building withour ARSession makes tracking work again, and I think also the anchors, I will test this better tomorrow. Without ARSession of course other ARFoundation features might not work, but we'll see if this does the trick for this specific combination of ASA and Vuforia

Comment: I'm trying to use WLT of mrtk i think it may be an good idea but I can't do what I want. Look about WLT and tell what you thinking about this.

Comment: I tested removing ARSession and indeed this solves this issue. Can both track with Vuforia and download Azure Spatial Anchors again

Comment: We removed WLT from our software. It moves your camera origin which I think you do not want. Vuforia can not handle that and your markers will have a large offset. There is no replacement I think of world anchors yet as we had in Unity 2019, but I think this is a nice topic for another post 

Comment: Yes to remove ARSession Vuforia working but i fon't know if you have the same issue but when i get my spatial anchor from the second device my objet not appear at the same postion of my first device do you have an idea ?

Comment: There can be more than one anchor in your room. You should check if the Id’s match and only accept the anchor with the same Id.

Comment: Thanks Tom. My problem comes from the Microsoft tutorial. I had to move my AR SESSION ORIGIN to another gameobject ... Have a good time